# Sequence of writing a File in C#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

```
System.IO.BinaryWriter outfile;

System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(some_object.text, System.IO.FileMode.Create);

outfile = new System.IO.BinaryWriter(fs);

outfile.Write('A');  // Line 1
outfile.Write('B');  // Line 2
outfile.Write('C');  // Line 3
outfile.Write( Convert.ToUInt16(some_object.text, 16) );   // Line 4
outfile.Write((ushort)0);  // Line 5
```

Here i declare a BinaryWriter for creating my output file.
What i need to know clearly is how the file is exactly being written? 
Meaning, that Line 1, 2, 3 write the file Byte by Byte meaning 1 byte at a time if i am correct??

This `some_object.text` holds a value `2000`.

How many bytes does `Line 4` exactly write?? (2 Bytes/16 Bits since UInt16 of is 16 bits) ?

Comment: None of those will ever write anything.  You only declare a variable that might hold a binary writer, but you never attach an instance to it.  Your writer is still `null`.  After fixing this, I suggest you actually compile and run the code, and then look at the file to find out.

Comment: @user667389, you would be amazed how many times a day someone posts questions that all boil down to not actually instantiating an object. @Joel Coehoorn didn't know if you were one of those people. Whatever you post is what we have to assume is your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the chart from MSDN to see how many bytes are written:

[`BinaryWriter.Write` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The `BinaryWriter` uses the `BitConverter` class to create sequences of bytes that are written to the underlying stream. A great way to understand what is going on, at the lowest level, is to use .NET Reflector. It can decompile assemblies and easily be used to figure out framework implementation details.

Most of the binary write methods use the native representation in little endian (though the endian is architecture specific and varies between platforms such as XBOX and Windows). The only exception to this are strings. Strings are by default encoded using UTF-8 encoding.